# Dirac points protected by PT symmetry?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry, dirac-equation

I am reading, in a paper titled [Twisted bilayer graphene in a parallel magnetic field](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.04185) (Kwan et al., 2019), that Dirac points are protected by $C_{2z}T$ symmetry. In particular, the authors write

> Combined time-reversal (TRS) and two-fold rotation $C_{2z}T$ (realized here as $\sigma_x K\{r → −r\}$, where K is complex conjugation) quantizes the Berry phase to $0$ or $\pi$, endowing the Dirac points with a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ charge and protecting them from gapping out individually.

I do understand the symmetry and can verify it for the Hamiltonian they consider. I however do not understand this argument about Berry phase and why it protects the Dirac points. Can anyone elaborate?